# Save text in UTF-8 via Batch

Tags: batch-file, encoding, utf-8

I am still working on a converter for .m3u playlist files that ports them from a Windows Media Player generated format into a format that gets accepted by the Teamspeak 3 plugin "Soundboard".

The main converter is finished now and I encountered a last problem:
When writing the new code with a Batch script it gets saved into an ANSI encoded file using `echo a-lot-of-text-and-code >> 3.txt` and it seems like the plugin can only open UTF-8 encoded files.

Is there any way to change the encoding of 3.txt from ANSI to UTF-8 with Batch only?

Regards, Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took a bit of experimentation, but I successfully tweaked [Simon Sheppard's UCS-2 encode method](http://ss64.com/nt/type.html) to encode a file as UTF-8 with batch.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

:: utf8.bat infile outfile
:: convert infile to utf8 and save as outfile

if not exist "%~1" goto usage
if "%~2"=="" goto usage

set "infile=%~f1"
set "outfile=%~f2"

:: store current console codepage to var
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%I in ('chcp') do set "_codepage=%%I"

:: temporarily change console codepage to UTF-8
>NUL chcp 65001

:: set byte order mark for outfile
>"%outfile%" set /p "=ï»¿" <NUL

:: dump infile to outfile encoded as UTF-8
>>"%outfile%" type "%infile%"

:: restore console to original codepage
>NUL chcp %_codepage%

goto :EOF

:usage
echo Usage: %~nx0 infile outfile
```

This script itself needs to be saved in ANSI encoding, though.

Comment: Worked perfectly fine! One question: WHY does the script have to be in ANSI itself? I mean, is there an obvious reason for it that I don't see? But thanks already!

Comment: Windows treats the BOM as an erroneous command and complains.  And whatever instruction is on the first line fails.  The script might work if it's saved as utf-8 without BOM, though.  Not sure.  Feel free to experiment.

Comment: And another question: what does the "setlocal" without any futher command do? I only know the "setlocal enabledelayedexpansion" command to work with variables in a for-loop. Is this doing the same or does this have another meaning?

Comment: `setlocal` limits the scope of any variables defined within the script to the script itself.  Variables set after calling `setlocal` are forgotten when the script exits (or when `endlocal` is encountered).  See [this detailed explanation](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) of why this is considered good practice.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to get used to it for further scripts!